# Does the Leray projector preserve compact support?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given a vector field $u \in [L^2(\mathbb{R^3})]^3$ it is well known that there exists a Helmholtz-Weyl decomposition $$u = h + \nabla g,$$
where $h \in [L^2(\mathbb{R^3})]^3$ is divergence free (in the weak sense) and $g \in H^1(\mathbb{R^3})$. Using this decomposition we can define the Leray projection of $u$ as $\mathbb{P}(u) = h$.

My question is the following. Suppose we have a function $\varphi \in [C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R^3})]^3$. Is it then true that $\mathbb{P}(\varphi)$ is also compactly supported? In other words, does taking the Leray projection preserve compact support?

In terms of a solution I was thinking that it is most natural to just look on the frequency side since we have an exact formula for the Leray projection in terms of the Fourier transform. Indeed, 
$$\widehat{\mathbb{P}(\varphi)}(\xi) = \widehat{\varphi}(\xi) - c\frac{\xi\cdot \hat{\varphi}(\xi)}{|\xi|^2}\xi,$$
where $c$ is a complex constant that depends on how you define your Fourier transform (which is irrelevant here). From the above expression it is clear that it suffices to see if the smooth function with Fourier transform given by 
$$\frac{\xi\cdot \hat{\varphi}(\xi)}{|\xi|^2}\xi$$
is compactly supported. Im am not sure whether or not this is the case. Any thoughts?